# Problems with MYSQL use 3 tables in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with a mysql query, I would like to create a query with multiple table's and be able to search or specific columns within all three tables at once, Database and tables are already created and filled.
(sorry if this is easy but i'm fairly new at mysql)

Example:

table 1

```
`ID`,`number`,`name`,`genre`,`location`,`type` 
1, 1001, Linkin Park, Rock, L001, cd
2, 1002, 3 doors down, Alternative, L002, cd
3, 1003, golden earring, Rock, L003, cd
```

table 2

```
`ID`,`number`,`name`,`genre`,`location`,`type` 
1, 1001, Kill bill, Action, L001, dvd
2, 1002, Hulk, Action, L002, dvd
3, 1003, Driven, Action, L003, dvd
```

table 2

```
`ID`,`number`,`name`,`genre`,`location`,`type` 
1, 1001, Call of Duty, Action, L001, Game
2, 1002, Battlefield, Action, L002, Game
3, 1003, Red Alert, strategy, L003, Game
```

something like:

```
SELECT 'number', 'name', 'genre', 'location', 'type' FROM tb1, tb2, tb3 WHERE type = 'Game'
```

Comment: The first question is why do you have those 3 tables? All data could fit in one. There might be a reason, but instead of trying to make a query, I will try to refactor the database.

Comment: if none of the records in those tables share anything in common other than structure, then you can't join them. sql `join` is for RELATED tables. you'd probably need a union query: `select ... from table1 union all select ... from table2 union all select ... table3`

Comment: Because it makes everything a little more organized, games of all kind within the games table (example: Playstation, pc and xbox are the types of games) and the same with dvd (dvd, blueray, 3d etc) and music (cd, dvd, lp)

Comment: You need to reconsider database design, as has been suggested below. Create one table with columns ID, number, name, genre, location, type. Then add an additional column to differentiate between the three different groups (seems to be music, movies, and games). Then insert all the data into this table based upon that grouping. Selecting the data you need then will be as simple as `SELECT * FROM  combinedTable`. If you want only movies, it becomes `SELECT * FROM combinedTable WHERE group = 'movies'` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can achieve what you want is making a `UNION` of all the tables, as follows:

```
 SELECT `number`, `name`, `genre`, `location`, `type` FROM 
( SELECT `number`, `name`, `genre`, `location`, `type` FROM tb1
  UNION ALL
   SELECT `number`, `name`, `genre`, `location`, `type` FROM tb2
   UNION ALL 
  SELECT `number`, `name`, `genre`, `location`, `type` FROM tb3 ) tb123
WHERE tb123.`type` = 'Game'
```

But I would actually recommend you look into setting up your database differently . For example, put everything into one table.

Comment: `'number', 'name', 'genre', 'location', 'type'`  should srapped with ``

Comment: thanks, wil look if this will work, if not than i will just rebuild my database

Comment: Thanks @underscore, fixed it. Initially just copy-pasted from the OP.